# Query 1: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: cassandra

When I run this query :

```
SELECT * FROM recipient WHERE expr(recipient_index, '{
    sort:{field: "fname", reverse: true }
}');
```

I am getting the below error in cassandra:

```
Query 1: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

But if I run the same query in other table it is working fine.

Can some look into this give the result please  why this is happening only in the single table.

Comment: `expr` is not valid CQL.  That's not going to work on _any_ Cassandra table.

Comment: we have applied lucen index  so that  expr comes under lucen syntax  for other quieries are working fine with expr